psql on WSL2 cannot connect find localhost in order to connect. (localhost is in /etc/hosts)
UPDATE
I reached my goal already: performed the operation from inside the pg instance and used docker cp command to get the dump out of the container.
Still would like to know the answer to the networking question:
I installed postgres in WSL2 in order to get access to postgres client tools in order to do a pg_dump from a docker instance of pg (docker running in WSL2), to a cloud instance of pg. I am running the psql command from my WSL2 / ubuntu terminal.
I cannot connect to the docker instance even using just psql.
I tried psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U <username> as well as psql -h localhost -U <username>
and both gave the error:
psql: error: could not translate host name "127.0.0.1" to address: Name or service not known
psql: error: could not translate host name "localhost" to address: Name or service not known

And yet /etc/hosts in WSL ubuntu contains 127.0.0.1       localhost and pgAdmin (which I guess strictly speaking runs in Windows proper) can connect using hostname localhost.
Then I thought since the pg instance is actually running in docker, in WSL, I'll also try the docker host ip using a command i found: docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <servicNameHere>
But I got the same error, even though a different docker web app which connects to the database is able to do so, from a browser with this same docker ip. To be fair all the services are on the same docker network but still.
Completely at a loss to why I can't connect from outside docker.
